# Create multiple custom error message(user message) for validation in list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, validation

How to create Create multiple custom error message(user message) for validation in list ?

Ex: I created a long validation formula ,I want to generate a specific message based on wherever my validation fails and not a generalized message for my complete validation formula.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of validations at list level:

1. Column validation: Here you could validate the values for a particular field. You can configure this from the `edit column` page - **with different messages for different columns**.
2. Item validation: You need to use this when you have a rule that requires values of multiple columns. You can configure this from list settings -> validation settings.

However you cannot have two item validations configured.

So if you have multiple rules that require more than one column value to validate against, I would suggest two alternatives:

1. Place a content editor web part on top of your `edit item` or `new item` form, and write these rules in plain text. So when any validation fails, users can read all these rules.
2. You could run these validations using JavaScript. Again you would need to add the script to your `edit` or `new` page, and then based on the validation errors, you can give different alerts on screen.